# Why do OpenGL methods not return anything?

Tags: c++, opengl

This is just out of curiosity. I couldn't help but noticing that none of the OpenGL methods return anything, even though some of the methods would seem to be more typically implemented with a return.

For example, `glGenBuffers` has two parameters, the number of buffers you want to generate, and variable you want to store them in. However, I would think that most people would code it as a method that only takes one parameter, the number of buffers you would like to create, and return those buffer(s). Is this for speed reasons? Or perhaps some other antiquitous reason?

Comment: Well, there *are* functions that return values, that fit into a primitive variable. glCreateShader and glCreateProgram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, it is hard to return an array of anything without introducing dynamic memory allocation.

So to "return" multiple names from `glGenBuffers (...)`, the easiest solution is to pass a pointer to an array and have the API call store the generated names in the pre-allocated array.

Comment: Not only that, it's for portability. If it returned an array of dynamically allocated memory, that would add a dependence on the C standard library and would also require the user to free that memory. By never returning memory a GL implementation allocates dynamically, those issues are completely avoided.

Comment: Actually, it is the only sane way to do so. I would literally hate library that allocates memory when it really shouldn't, and doesn't provide a way to avoid it.

Comment: @keltar now a reason to hate the library is the statefulness of it (binding buffers before using them), I would vastly prefer the EXT_direct_state_access extension for that

Comment: @ratchetfreak I wasn't talking specifically about GL, but I'm still ok with that. Anyway, isn't 4.5 allows direct state access everywhere?

Comment: How about [glGetShaderiv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml), which only returns a `GLint`?